# Add Material Icon in React-Toastify Message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, alert, react-toastify

This is the code defined in one folder. I am tring to add the material Icon in this. But it is showing the error

*React' must be in scope when using JSX*

```
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import ErrorIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Error';

const Alert = (type, message) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'warning':
            return toast.warning(message)
        case 'error':
            return toast.error(<div><ErrorIcon/> {message}</div>) // look this line
        case 'success':
            return toast.success(message)
        case 'info':
            return toast.info(message)
        case 'dark':
            return toast.dark(message)
        default:
            return toast(message)
    }
}
export default Alert;
```

Accessing the code like this...

```
import Alert from '../utils/toster.js';

Alert('error', 'Try Again')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please import react on top of your file that used JSX.

```
import React from 'react'
```